# Binary Search Tree searching in java

Tags: java, search, insert, binary-search-tree

I'm attempting to make a BST program that is capable of inserting a given number and then telling the user if the number is in the BST by saying either true or false. However, even if the number is inserted, it always registers as false. Would anyone be able to tell me where I am going wrong here? I can supply the rest of my class files if they are needed.

```
public class BinarySearchTree implements BST
{
private int n;
private Node r;
private Node l;

public void enter(int num)
{
    Node node = new Node(num);

    if (num < node.getData())
    {
        if (node.getL() != null)
        {
            insert(num);
        }

        else
        {
            node.setL(new Node(num));
        }
    }

    else if (num > node.getData())
    {
        if (node.getR() != null)
        {
            insert(num);
        }

        else
        {
            node.setR(new Node(num));
        }
    }
}

public boolean search (int num)
{
    if (num == this.n)
    {
        return true;
    }

    else if (num > this.n)
    {
        if (r == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else if (num < this.n)
    {
        if (l == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You

```
        insert(num);
```

both to the left and right, does insert() check if it has to go left or right again?

```
node
```

is used but not declared anywhere.

and you get the idea hopefully, post the whole thing.

Also, while your problem is returning false. Your code returns true way more often than that (and technically shouldn't return true just because num > this.n and we got a right OR left). So your first issue is your building of the tree, which HAS to be wrong for you to obtain false, once you fix that, fix the search.

Answer (score 0):

If this is not a homwork or similar stuff:
Use a TreeSet which implements a Red-Black-Tree

```
Set<Number> numbers = new TreeSet<Number>();
numbers.add(...);

if (numbers.contains(...)) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In BST class,can keep the search and insert functions along with one root Node.You are keeping Node internal variables also in BST, which is frankly, confusing.

   2. If you add null-check to your insert function, you won't need another enter function.

   3. Also your search function is completely wrong, because you are checking for equality only in first level. You have to do it recursively on both left and right till you find the key or run out of nodes.